# Dart Polymer: Removing element from List

Tags: data-binding, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a custom element with some models. Here is the code for custom element.

message-element.html

```
<polymer-element name="message-element" attributes="message">
  <template>

    <table class="table">
    <tr template repeat="{{attrib in attribs}}">
      <td><paper-input name="message-attrib-name" label="New Attribute" value="{{attrib.name}}"></paper-input></td>
      <td>
        <paper-input name="message-attrib-value" label="" value="{{attrib.value}}"></paper-input>

        <core-icon-button icon="check" on-tap="{{addAttribute}}"></core-icon-button>
        <core-icon-button icon="highlight-remove" on-tap="{{deleteAttribute}}"></core-icon-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="message-element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

message-element.dart

```
@CustomTag('message-element')
class MessageElement extends PolymerElement with Observable {
  @published Message message;
  @observable List<Attribute> attribs = toObservable([]);
  @observable Attribute att;

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MessageElement.created() : super.created() {
    polymerCreated();
  }

  attached() {
    att = new Attribute('', '');
    attribs.add(att);
    message.attributes = attribs; // initialize with 1 attrib
  }

  void addAttribute(Event event, Object detail, Node sender) {
    att = new Attribute('', '');
    attribs.add(att);
  }

  void deleteAttribute(Event event, Object detail, Node sender) {
    // remove the clicked attrib
  }
}
```

attribs is shown in a modal dialog and each attrib in attribs has couple inputs with add and delete buttons. Adding element is working fine. How do I delete the clicked attrib from attribs. I'm calling void deleteAttribute(Event event, Object detail, Node sender) on on-tap on delete button. In this call I need to delete the attrib from the list but how do I get the details of tapped attrib so I can delete that from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Polymer >= 1.0.0**

```
@reflectable
void someClickHandler(dom.Event event, [_]) {
  // for native events (like on-click)
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(event);
  // or for custom events (like on-tap, works also for native events)
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(convertToJs(event));
  var value = model.jsElement['items']; 
  // or 
  var value = model.jsElement[$['mylist'].attributes['as']];
  // if you used the `as="somename"` 
  // in your <core-list> or <template is="dom-repeat">
}
```

There is an open issue related to custom events: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/624

**Polymer <= 0.16.0**

```dart
import 'package:template_binding/template_binding.dart' as tb;
...    

void deleteAttribute(Event event, Object detail, Node sender) {
  tb.TemplateInstance ti = tb.nodeBind(event.target).templateInstance; 
  var value = ti.model.value as Attribute;
  attribs.remove(value);
}
```

See [In Polymer.js children of a template have a reference to the template, how can this be done in Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530054) for more details.

Comment: This is giving me following warning on var value = ti.model.value as Inner 'The name 'Inner' is not a type and cannot be used in an 'as' expression'

Comment: OK great its working fine now. But I don't understand it. Can you give me some pointers to get insight into it. I'm still learning Dart and Polymer I would really appreciate if you could give me links to learn quick and in depth. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I don't have links, such "advanced" things aren't documented well yet. What Polymer does, is to assign an Expando  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358018)  to each node it creates, holding a reference to the model instance (Attribute in your case) dynamically and with the code in my answer you acquire that referenced model instance from the node passed with the event.

Comment: I'm following a lot of discussions, and GitHub repo updates (issues, pull requests) where I sometimes find some interesting pieces. Also the [polymer] tag on StackOverflow for Polymer.js. Almost anything working in Polymer.js can somehow be translated to Dart. I'm sure documentation will become better when Polymer is stable (1.0)